# Mongoose: How to update value in array at index given from variable?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

options.votes is an array.

This code works:

```
Poll.findOneAndUpdate({title},{$inc:{'options.votes.0':1}}
```

I need to replace 0 for a variable.

This does not work:

```
const query = 'options.votes.'+variable
Poll.findOneAndUpdate({title},{$inc:{query:1}}
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just an object with a string key

```
var obj = {};

obj['options.votes.'+variable] = 1;

Poll.findOneAndUpdate({title},{$inc:obj})
```

or with ES2015 and dynamic keys

```
const query = 'options.votes.'+variable;
Poll.findOneAndUpdate({title},{$inc:{[query]:1}})
```